# IIS hosting ASP Core running on .Net Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis

I can't find any documentation on how to host an ASP Core 2.x application running on .Net Framework on IIS 10. Does it use the same AspNetCoreModule as when running on .Net Core or should I use the ASP.Net IIS module? What other IIS configuration is required?

Comment: You can read this documentation https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/. It should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "ASP Core 2.x" I assume you mean ASP .NET Core 2.1 (as earlier versions are out of support.

If you visit the .NET downloads page:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet

Find your runtime version, and click to visit the download page for that version.  There you will find the links to download the correct Hosting Bundle, which you will want to install into IIS to host your .NET Core app.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: That documentation states that apps that "Has 64-bit native dependencies" are _not_ supported, and the main reason to run ASP.Net Core on .Net Framework would be precisely to support native dependencies. So I don't think that documentation really describes how to correctly host ASP.Net Core on .Net Framework, (or if it does it doesn't make much sense to me).

Comment: .NET Core and .NET Framework are different things, so I guess I'm not following your question.  The documentation (under the "Supported Platform" header) states to use a 32-bit SDK unless you have native 64-bit dependencies, in which you need to use a 64-bit SDK/runtime.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#supported-platforms-3

Comment: ASP Net Core is a framework library. It can be run on either the Net Core or .Net Framework runtime. It can be useful to run ASP Core on .Net Framework as that supports native dependencies that the Net Core runtime does not. However the documentation does not describe the correct IIS deployment strategy and configuration for an ASP Core service running on .Net Framework.

Comment: Sounds like your .NET Core app requires .NET Framework libraries.  If that's the case, I would imagine as long as that .NET Framework version is installed on the same server as your .NET Core application, it would function correctly.

Comment: ASP Net Core can be run just when you have installed the .Net Core framework. On Linux or Windows. Doesn't matter. Don't make it complicated.  Just read the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and go to [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet) and download the version of .Net Core you want and enjoy running ASP.NET Core smoothly.